# xfce keyboard setup

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, keyboard-layout

I am accessing Ubuntu Desktop version 16.04.1 LTS from Windows 10 with RDP but can't get a UK keyboard layout working which means that office applications are very difficult to use.

I have downloaded and installed http://archive.xfce.org/src/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin/0.5/xfce4-xkb-plugin-0.5.4.3.tar.bz2 but when I try to change the keyboard layout I can only see the US KB option as you can see from the screenshot. Is there something else I should be doing other than installing to make this work please?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to this problem from a friend so adding it here to help others that may find the same problem. The problem is that xrdp always uses km-0409.ini (US keyboard) & is apparently not configurable to use anything else. The best solution is to download a copy of km-0809.ini with UK keyboard definitions in it. I found one that works at c-nergy.be/downloads/km-0809.ini. I first saved a copy of the existing km-0409.ini in /etc/xrdp then replaced the contents of the file with the downloaded version. Restart of the xrdp session it all works as required with a UK keyboard mapping. Presumably the same could be applied to any other keyboard layout variant if you can get hold of a suitable keyboard definition file.